# :hover text elements over an image using HTML and CSS

Tags: html, css

Currently I have an image inside a div tag. This div tag holds an image and a container box which holds my content. I want the content to be hidden at first, and only if the content is hovered on, the content should up with an animation. Here's a reference image of what I want to show when my card is hovered upon:

[image]

So far I've tried adding the :hover property to my content box but the layout isn't showing up right.

What I'm currently doing in html:

```
<div class="container">
      <div class="imgBox">
        <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_avatar.png" />
        <div class="nameHolder">
          <div class="leftText">
            <div style="font-size: 14px; color: #fff;">Random Name</div>
            <div style="font-size: 12px; color: rgb(248, 232, 6);">
              Software Engineer
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

My CSS for the same:

```
.container {
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
}

.imgBox {
  width: 200px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: #000;
  position: relative;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.nameHolder {
  width: 100%;
  height: 20%;
  background-color: #0e2043;
  margin-top: -0px;
  transition: 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.imgBox:hover .nameHolder {
  margin-top: -50px;
  transition-delay: 0.3s;
}

.leftText {
  justify-content: center;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  vertical-align: middle;
  top: 50%;
}
```

I've added my codesandbox for reference to the code: https://codesandbox.io/s/hungry-gagarin-bpsdw?file=/index.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Check this out. This is what you wanted !??**

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: coral;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
}

.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  padding: 1rem;
  bottom: -100%;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  transition: bottom 250ms ease;
}

.container:hover .overlay {
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_avatar.png" />
  <div class="overlay">
    <h2> Random Name </h2>
    <p> Software Engineer </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, this is kind of what I wanted but as you see in my reference picture, initially you are able to see some part of the blue container which then expands upwards. Here I cant see anything initially.

Comment: down-voted for missing explaination. Code only answers are considered low-quality as they neither explain the issue nor the solution. As such they are hard to understand for the OP and therfore hard to reproduce.